# Java: Creating a GUI with a Button Adder

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

i'm trying to create a JFrame with a button. When I press that button, another button appears in the frame as "Button 1", if I click again then comes the "Button 2" and it continues... If I click in "button X" (being X a number) it should disappear. I guess that I have a problem in the actionListener, but I can't identify it.

```
public class ButtonAdder {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;
    private AddButtonListener listener;

    public ButtonAdder(){
        frame = new JFrame("ButtonAdder");
        button = new JButton("Add new button");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        listener = new AddButtonListener();

        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        button.addActionListener(listener);

        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setLocation(500, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }

    public void execute() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


 public class AddButtonListener implements ActionListener  {
   private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;
    private AddButtonListener listener;
     int current_button_number = 1;  

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == button) {
                // Create a new button:
                JButton newButton = new JButton("Button " + current_button_number++);

                // Change the appearance of the button:
                newButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                newButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

                newButton.addActionListener(this);
                frame.add(newButton);      
            } else {
                // The source of the event is the button that was pressed 
                // and that we should remove:
                JButton button_pressed = (JButton) e.getSource();

                // We remove the button from the content pane:
                frame.remove(button_pressed);                               

                // Ask the content pane to eventually redraw itself:
                frame.repaint();                                
            }
            // validate() causes the content pane to re-layout the buttons:
            frame.validate();      
         }

}

public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ButtonAdder button = new ButtonAdder();
    button.execute();

 }

}
```

Comment: Your JFrame has a BorderLayout. frame.add(newButton) adds the new button to CENTER - only one component will be displayed there.  Use a different layout, such as a BoxLayout.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems I saw in your code is the references to your objects. An example is the `frame`. The `frame` in your `AddButtonListener` is not the same as the `frame` in the `ButtonAdder`. If you shall put all your code in one class file and remove the `private JFrame frame;` in the `AddButtonListener`, this problem can be addressed. And also the testing of the `button` in the `AddButtonListener` has a problem. One way to test the correct button is to test its text. In the code below, I put `if(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().equals("Add new button"))`. The layout of your frame is also `Borderlayout`. I just change it to `Flowlayout` to let you see the effect of adding new buttons. If you want to stick with the `BorderLayout`, you must find a way so the `AddButtonListener` knows where to position the next button that will be added (center, left, right, south).

If all codes in one file:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonAdder {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;
    private AddButtonListener listener;

    public ButtonAdder(){
        frame = new JFrame("ButtonAdder");
        button = new JButton("Add new button");
//      frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        listener = new AddButtonListener();

//      frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(listener);

        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setLocation(500, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void execute() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    class AddButtonListener implements ActionListener  {
        //private JFrame frame;
        private JButton button;
        private AddButtonListener listener;
        int current_button_number = 1;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().equals("Add new button")) {
                // Create a new button:
                JButton newButton = new JButton("Button " + current_button_number++);

                // Change the appearance of the button:
                newButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                newButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

                newButton.addActionListener(this);
                frame.add(newButton);
            } else {
                // The source of the event is the button that was pressed
                // and that we should remove:
                JButton button_pressed = (JButton) e.getSource();

                // We remove the button from the content pane:
                frame.remove(button_pressed);

                // Ask the content pane to eventually redraw itself:
                frame.repaint();
            }
            // validate() causes the content pane to re-layout the buttons:
            frame.validate();
        }

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ButtonAdder button = new ButtonAdder();
        button.execute();

    }
}
```

If you really want to separate the classes as your original code does, my suggestion is to pass the `frame` object to the `AddButtonListener` class. And then create a constructor with the `JFrame` as the parameter. You shall then assign it to the local `frame` in the `AddButtonListener`.

If ButtonAdder class is in separate file:

```
public class ButtonAdder {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;
    private AddButtonListener listener;

    public ButtonAdder(){
        frame = new JFrame("ButtonAdder");
        button = new JButton("Add new button");
//      frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        listener = new AddButtonListener(frame); // pass frame

//      frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(listener);

        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setLocation(500, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void execute() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If AddButtonListener class is in a separate file:

```
class AddButtonListener implements ActionListener  {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;
    private AddButtonListener listener;
    int current_button_number = 1;


    public  AddButtonListener(JFrame f) { // create constructor
        frame = f;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText().equals("Add new button")) {
            // Create a new button:
            JButton newButton = new JButton("Button " + current_button_number++);

            // Change the appearance of the button:
            newButton.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            newButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

            newButton.addActionListener(this);
            frame.add(newButton);
        } else {
            // The source of the event is the button that was pressed
            // and that we should remove:
            JButton button_pressed = (JButton) e.getSource();

            // We remove the button from the content pane:
            frame.remove(button_pressed);

            // Ask the content pane to eventually redraw itself:
            frame.repaint();
        }
        // validate() causes the content pane to re-layout the buttons:
        frame.validate();
    }

}
```